# Take specific value from specific line from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList which contains some infos .

Every line has this pattern : name age sex job .

I'm searching for a way to take for example the every value separately and to assign them in different variables. I've search the web , but I came out to nothing ! So if there is someone that could help me I would appreciate it !

I have no idea how to do it so I can't provide code ! Soory I'm newbie in java .

Comment: Split the line and save in the collection

Comment: An `ArrayList` doesn't have lines. Do you mean by reading a file? Read a Java IO tutorial.

Comment: Check out Java's Scanner utility

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mean hypothetical lines !

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Person` that will hold your data:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String sex;
    private String job;
    //class constructor...
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Then, read the file. For every line in the file, create an instance of `Person` class and store it in a `List`. I'll do this in pseudocode, it's up to you the concrete implementation (otherwise it would be me doing your homework =\):

```
List<Person> people <- new ArrayList<Person>()
open_file(theFile)
while not_end_of_file
    String name <- read_text
    String age <- read_int
    String sex <- read_text
    String job <- read_text
    Person person <- new Person()
    person->setName(name)
    //similar for other fields...
    people->add(person)
end while
```

Comment: you didn't understand what I want to say ! i haven't a file ! JUst thinking about the ArrayList as a ListView in Android !

Comment: @gimbo well, instead of a file can be another kind of data source. The algorithm is still the same. Looks like you need to review Java basics one more time.

Comment: Maybe I need as I said I'm newbie ... But i insist in opinion that you haven't really understand my question

Comment: @gimbo in short, you need a class `Person` that holds your data (which is in my answer) and a `List<Person>` where you will store your data (which is in my answer too). The way you fill this data is what you have not explained in your answer, so the current design applies for your problem. If you still have issues, edit your question and add (do not remove) content explaining your problem in details. And like you, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a List of Strings.  If so, you could call the String `split(String regex)` method to get a String[] back.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create a `Person` object which would contain a name, age, sex and job.

Then you could create an Arraylist of type Person.

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

The person class would look something like this:

```
public class Person {
  String name, sex, jobTitle;
  int age;

  public Person(String name){
    this.name = name;
  } 
}
```